# Elementos de un formulario - Bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap

Alguien que me pueda explicar para que sirven las siguientes clases de bootstrap en formularios:

- form-check-label
- form-check-input

Comment: Para dar ciertos estilos a tus elementos https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase form-check sirve para darle márgenes apropiados a tus checkboxes o a tus botones de radio (radio buttons).
Dentro de la clase form-check deberías usar la clase form-check-label para las etiquetas de las entradas y form-check-input dentro de dichas etiquetas para las entradas propiamente dichas. Qeudaría así:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="">Option 1
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="">Option 2
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="" disabled>Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Como mencioné antes, esta clase form-check sirve para checkboxes(type="checkbox"), o para radio buttons (type="radio"). La diferencia principal entre estos dos es que los checkboxes solamente permiten seleccionar más de una opción, mientras que los radiobuttons solamente permiten seleccionar una de las opciones.
Puedes encontrar información y ejemplos en la [documentación oficial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/), y en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp).